# How to extract floats from string and capture individually into object?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have the following code and I would like to get 1.00 and 1.04 and declare it in an object. But I am having problems, please help. Here is my code

```
String body = "You have bought USD 1.00 Whatsapp for 784024487. Your new wallet balance is USD 1.04. Happy Birthday EcoCash for turning 7years. Live Life the EcoCash Way.";
String regex="([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)";
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(body);
while(matcher.find())
        {
            String detail = "Airtime";
            transUtilsList.add(new TransUtils(detail,+matcher.group(),matcher.group()));
        }
```

I would like the first matcher.group() to capture the first float which is 1.00 and the second matcher.group() to capture the second float which is 1.04 but they all capture 1.00 instead. How do I do that?

Comment: Why not just use a counter variable? The current regex is much more efficient than`"([0-9]+[.][0-9]+).*?([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two float numbers in your string, you can make a regex which captures both the float numbers into two different capture groups, like the following regex,

```
(\d+\.\d+).*(\d+\.\d+)
```

And then access both the matches using `matcher.group(1)` and `matcher.group(2)`

Check your modified Java code,

```
String body = "You have bought USD 1.00 Whatsapp for 784024487. Your new wallet balance is USD 1.04. Happy Birthday EcoCash for turning 7years. Live Life the EcoCash Way.";
String regex = "(\\d+\\.\\d+).*(\\d+\\.\\d+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(body);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("First float: " + matcher.group(1) + ", Second float: " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Prints,

```
First float: 1.00, Second float: 1.04
```

In case you have many float numbers in your string, you may have to adjust your regex to use `.*?` instead of `.*` to capture immediate adjacent float numbers or the way you want to capture them.

Also, the parenthesis in your regex are redundant if you are enclosing your whole pattern into them. Hence, `([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)` and `[0-9]+[.][0-9]+` are almost same because you don't need to use capturing groups when your capturing group is exactly the whole match. So you can remove them and also, in your code you weren't actually using group capture like I did in my code. When you access match using `matcher.group()`, it gives you full match and when you access using `matcher.group(1)`, then it gives you text captured by first group but as in your case, both `matcher.group()` and `matcher.group(1)` will be same for reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

use [Matcher.find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) instead of [Matcher.group()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())

as mentioned in the docs,

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

I would prefer `find` over `group` in case your body contains more than 2 occurrences in future.